# Custom JSON Result in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I created custom `ActionResult` (simplified):

```
public class FastJSONResult : ActionResult
{
    public string JsonData { get; private set; }

    public FastJSONResult(object data)
    {
        JsonData = JSON.Instance.ToJSON(data);
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/json";
        response.Output.Write(JsonData);
    }
}
```

And use it from my WebApi controller:

```
public ActionResult GetReport()
{
   var report = new Report();
   return new FastJSONResult(report);
}
```

Now the problem is, despite the fact that in `FastJSONResult` constructor my object serializes perfectly, `ExecuteResult` never gets called and in response I end up with object like

```
{"JsonData":"{my json object as a string value}"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your response looks good, that is the same response you would get if you used `return Json(report, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @DZL ok, maybe, but that's not nice, isn't it?

Comment: @DZL also, my point is, why 'ExecuteResult' is not being called?

Comment: Do you override OnResultExecuting or something like that on your controller?

Comment: @DZL no, but i think this has something to do with WebApi andRegular controllers difference in pipeline. Seems like in WebApi i have to use formatters, not ActionResults

Comment: WebAPI will always serialize whatever object you return. I think you'll need to instead register a custom serializer for your class, something like this: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/09/30/custom-serialization-with-json-net-webapi-and-bsondocument.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it with custom formatter (simplified to post less code)

```
public class FastJsonFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
  private static JSONParameters _parameters = new JSONParameters()
  {
    public FastJsonFormatter()
    {
      SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
      SupportedEncodings.Add(new UTF8Encoding(false, true));
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
      return true;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
      return true;
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        var task = Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(() => JSON.Instance.ToObject(new StreamReader(readStream).ReadToEnd(), type));
        return task;
    }

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
      var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
         var json = JSON.Instance.ToJSON(value, _parameters);
         using (var w = new StreamWriter(writeStream)) w.Write(json);  
      });
      return task;
    }
}
```

In WebApiConfig.Register method:

```
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
config.Formatters.Add(new FastJsonFormatter());
```

And now I receive json object properly:
[image: Sample]